# When i'm going to format namenode ,i got error saying that org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: xml, hadoop

```
    pc83@pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p:~/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop$ hadoop namenode -format
    DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
    Instead use the hdfs command for it.

    15/10/09 16:02:11 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
    /************************************************************
    STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
    STARTUP_MSG:   host = pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p/127.0.1.1
    STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
    STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.6.0
    STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = /home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-framework-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-net-3.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-auth-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/apacheds-kerberos-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-recipes-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jets3t-0.9.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/httpclient-4.2.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/curator-client-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0-tests.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsp-api-2.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/htrace-core-3.0.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-nfs-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0-tests.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/activation-1.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-client-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jettison-1.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-json-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-client-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-common-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-api-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-launcher-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-3.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-guice-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/xz-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-core-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/junit-4.11.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/avro-1.7.4.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/guice-servlet-3.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/hadoop-annotations-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/asm-3.2.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jersey-server-1.9.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/paranamer-2.3.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0-tests.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.6.0.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
    STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
    STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79
    ************************************************************/
    15/10/09 16:02:11 INFO namenode.NameNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
    15/10/09 16:02:11 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
    15/10/09 16:02:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    [Fatal Error] yarn-site.xml:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    15/10/09 16:02:12 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf yarn-site.xml
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/pc83/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2352)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2340)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:888)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:907)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getLong(Configuration.java:1180)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.isSecurityEnabled(UserGroupInformation.java:319)


        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1379) Content is not allowed in prolog.

    15/10/09 16:02:12 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
    15/10/09 16:02:12 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
    /************************************************************
    SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p/127.0.1.1
    ************************************************************/
    pc83@pc83-ThinkCentre-M92p:~/Application/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop$
```

when i'm going to format namenode on my machine i got error saying that xml parsing  also it will says Content is not allowed in prolog.
to overcome this scenario what i have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your yarn-site.xml contains an extraneous character at the beginning (**"Content is not allowed in prolog"** - means there is some content before the start tag of the XML document).

I was able to reproduce this problem, by adding a "-" character at the beginning of "yarn-site.xml" (check - before **"\<\?xml>"**)

```
-<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
```

I too get the same error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/E:/hdp/hadoop-2.7.1.2.
3.0.0-2557/etc/hadoop/yarn-site.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is
not allowed in prolog.

        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2468)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:
2539)
        ... 15 more
15/10/09 21:37:59 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

To ensure that your "yarn-site.xml" is correct, just copy paste the contents of the file in an XML validator: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp. It'll point to the error in your document.

After correcting your "yarn-site.xml", your command should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Once  check your `hdfs-site.xml` file, remove spaces or unnecessary characteristics before `<?xml`. Then easily out the error.